# How to set set Android keyboard to capitalize first letter in Mobile Hybrid app

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on a hybrid app and having a problem while testing in Android (4.4). I am using Ionic (AngularJS+Cordova).

I have searched high and low for the answer to this problem to no avail. I am trying to make it so that when a text box has focus the mobile keyboard is set to capitalize the first letter. I DO NOT want it to only appear capitalized (text-transform), but actually have a capitalized value, but only if the user wants that.

It's almost like I want the shift key to get pressed automatically whenever a text input gets focus.

Comment: have you got a solution for this. I am behind same requirement

Comment: Yes, but it's a hack. I used a text-area with a reduced height to look like a textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can set attribute `autocapitalize="sentences"` on an input field to capitalize the first letter of each sentence.

[`autocapitalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autocapitalize) is the new attribute introduced in the HTML 5.3 which controls whether and how text input is automatically capitalized as it is entered/edited by the user.

Note that it doesn't affect behavior when typing on a physical keyboard. Instead, it affects the behavior of other input mechanisms, such as virtual keyboards on mobile devices and voice input.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with was to use a text-area input styles to look like a regular text-input. Android wants to capitalize text-areas automatically so this works.. even though it's a bit hacky.